# ngrok account token connection is not working

Tags: ngrok

in terminal:
ngrok config add-authtoken -----personal_TOKEN-----

when ı tryed for this ı'm getting this error

ı downloaded the pyngrok but still ı have this issue.
Thanks for any help !

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/selman/PycharmProjects/tringle-case/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyngrok/installer.py", line 94, in install_ngrok
    download_path = _download_file(url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/selman/PycharmProjects/tringle-case/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyngrok/installer.py", line 257, in _download_file
    raise e
  File "/home/selman/PycharmProjects/tringle-case/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyngrok/installer.py", line 235, in _download_file
    buffer = response.read(chunk_size)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 459, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 503, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/selman/PycharmProjects/tringle-case/venv/bin/ngrok", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/selman/PycharmProjects/tringle-case/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyngrok/ngrok.py", line 501, in main
    run(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/selman/PycharmProjects/tringle-case/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyngrok/ngrok.py", line 487, in run
    install_ngrok(pyngrok_config)
  File "/home/selman/PycharmProjects/tringle-case/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyngrok/ngrok.py", line 98, in install_ngrok
    installer.install_ngrok(pyngrok_config.ngrok_path)
  File "/home/selman/PycharmProjects/tringle-case/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyngrok/installer.py", line 98, in install_ngrok
    raise PyngrokNgrokInstallError("An error occurred while downloading ngrok from {}: {}".format(url, e))
pyngrok.exception.PyngrokNgrokInstallError: An error occurred while downloading ngrok from https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip: The read operation timed out
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is faulty. Try this:

ngrok.exe authtoken xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Replace xxxxxxx with your token.

Comment: I believe it's the difference between `ngrok` 2.x and 3.x. The docs are now pointing to 3.x, but a vast majority of people are still using 2.x. Especially if you're using the `pyngrok` package, it manages a 2.x binary.